# Ethereum paper wallet address generator with ability to upload your own graphic to give as gifts

Tags: cold-storage, paper-wallets

I'm looking to give eth to friends and family for christmas this year. But I wanted to upload my own background image if possible to an Ethereum paper wallet generator. Is there such a thing? I don't want to have to edit the paper wallet source code just to do this if I don't have to.

Also, I can also send erc20 tokens to any ethereum paper wallet address right?

Comment: I think it is better if you ask one question at a time.

Comment: The answer to your 2nd question is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a customizable one I made:

**Memory Paper Wallet**

source: https://github.com/xcubicle/memorypaperwallet

site: https://xcubicle.github.io/memorypaperwallet/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are a list of wallets that support ERC-20 tokens:

- MyEtherWallet (no download needed)
- MetaMask (Firefox and Chrome browser addon) Recommended
- Mist (Desktop)
- Parity (Desktop)
- imToken (iPhone)
- imToken (Android)
- Trust(iPhone)
- Trust(Android)
- Cipher(iPhone)
- Cipher(Android)

MyEtherWallet(MEW) is probably the easiest to create a paper wallet and edit with.

You can add an image by saving the source code of the HTML that is generated from the wallet, and inserting an `<img/>` tag with the source of your image. Alternatively, you could save as a PDF and use a PDF editing tool to edit the layout.